# Issues with if elseif statements in C code, only part of statements in last case are executed

Tags: c, if-statement

I have one issue with using the following if-elseif statement in C language, I am using Altera Monitor program as compiler as it is used to program the Nios II processor in the Altera development board.  Previously, when I only have four options of value ‘u’ (u can be 1,2,3 or 4) , I use switch statement and it works perfectly. Now, I need three sets of u (‘u1,u2 and u3, each u again can be 1,2,3 or 4), the switch statement does not work anymore, I don’t know why only one switch statement is allowed where I cant use three switch statements, so I changed from switch to if elseif as can be seen below….

The issue here is, it works perfectly for all four cases of ‘u1’ and all four cases of ‘u2’, the problem occurs for the last case of ‘u3’ when ‘u3’ is 4. I send the data to the serial port using UART so I know when u3==4, the data is sent but with some characters missing….

The code I posted here is lengthy but it is actually doing the same thing for three cases of u1, u2 and u3 but I thought it would be appropriate for me to show all of them

The output error is as shown in this image, only data 12 is not in proper value and format, the other eleven sets show the intended format:
[image]

EDITED: It is important to say that for txdata12, for all the trials, only the last ten ascii characters sent are correctly displayed, the first 16 digits are wrong.

EDITED: The declarations are:

```
int b=26;
unsigned char txdata1 [b];
unsigned char txdata2 [b];
unsigned char txdata3 [b];
unsigned char txdata4 [b];
unsigned char txdata5 [b];
unsigned char txdata6 [b];
unsigned char txdata7 [b];
unsigned char txdata8 [b];
unsigned char txdata9 [b];
unsigned char txdata10 [b];
unsigned char txdata11 [b];
unsigned char txdata12 [b];
```

The codes where the values are assigned, each arr1_v[3] for instance is different for each set of data and they are not constant
    int qq=26;

```
if (u1==1)

     {int MAT1[]={0,1,10, arr1_v[3], arr1_v[2], arr1_v[1],arr1_v[0],-1,arr1_q[7],arr1_q[6],arr1_q[5],arr1_q[4],arr1_q[3],arr1_q[2],arr1_q[1],arr1_q[0],-1,arr1_soc[3],arr1_soc[2],arr1_soc[1],arr1_soc[0],-1,arr1_index[1],arr1_index[0], -35,-38};
for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata1[i] = MAT1[i];  }

else if (u1==2)

    {int MAT2[]={0,2,10, arr1_v[3], arr1_v[2], arr1_v[1],arr1_v[0],-1,arr1_q[7],arr1_q[6],arr1_q[5],arr1_q[4],arr1_q[3],arr1_q[2],arr1_q[1],arr1_q[0],-1,arr1_soc[3],arr1_soc[2],arr1_soc[1],arr1_soc[0],-1,arr1_index[1],arr1_index[0], -35,-38};
for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata2[i] = MAT2[i];  }

else if (u1==3)

    {int MAT3[]={0,3,10, arr1_v[3], arr1_v[2], arr1_v[1],arr1_v[0],-1,arr1_q[7],arr1_q[6],arr1_q[5],arr1_q[4],arr1_q[3],arr1_q[2],arr1_q[1],arr1_q[0],-1,arr1_soc[3],arr1_soc[2],arr1_soc[1],arr1_soc[0],-1,arr1_index[1],arr1_index[0], -35,-38};
    for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata3[i] = MAT3[i];  }

else if (u1==4)

    {int MAT4[]={0,4,10, arr1_v[3], arr1_v[2], arr1_v[1],arr1_v[0],-1,arr1_q[7],arr1_q[6],arr1_q[5],arr1_q[4],arr1_q[3],arr1_q[2],arr1_q[1],arr1_q[0],-1,arr1_soc[3],arr1_soc[2],arr1_soc[1],arr1_soc[0],-1,arr1_index[1],arr1_index[0], -35,-38};
    for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata4[i] = MAT4[i];  }



u2=h2+1;
if (u2==1)

    {int MAT5[]={0,5,10, arr2_v[3], arr2_v[2], arr2_v[1],arr2_v[0],-1,arr2_q[7],arr2_q[6],arr2_q[5],arr2_q[4],arr2_q[3],arr2_q[2],arr2_q[1],arr2_q[0],-1,arr2_soc[3],arr2_soc[2],arr2_soc[1],arr2_soc[0],-1,arr2_index[1],arr2_index[0], -35,-38};
    for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata5[i] = MAT5[i];   }

else if (u2==2)

    {int MAT6[]={0,6,10, arr2_v[3], arr2_v[2], arr2_v[1],arr2_v[0],-1,arr2_q[7],arr2_q[6],arr2_q[5],arr2_q[4],arr2_q[3],arr2_q[2],arr2_q[1],arr2_q[0],-1,arr2_soc[3],arr2_soc[2],arr2_soc[1],arr2_soc[0],-1,arr2_index[1],arr2_index[0], -35,-38};
    for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata6[i] = MAT6[i]; }

else if (u2==3)

    {int MAT7[]={0,7,10, arr2_v[3], arr2_v[2], arr2_v[1],arr2_v[0],-1,arr2_q[7],arr2_q[6],arr2_q[5],arr2_q[4],arr2_q[3],arr2_q[2],arr2_q[1],arr2_q[0],-1,arr2_soc[3],arr2_soc[2],arr2_soc[1],arr2_soc[0],-1,arr2_index[1],arr2_index[0], -35,-38};
     for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata7[i] = MAT7[i];  }

else if (u2==4)

    {int MAT8[]={0,8,10, arr2_v[3], arr2_v[2], arr2_v[1],arr2_v[0],-1,arr2_q[7],arr2_q[6],arr2_q[5],arr2_q[4],arr2_q[3],arr2_q[2],arr2_q[1],arr2_q[0],-1,arr2_soc[3],arr2_soc[2],arr2_soc[1],arr2_soc[0],-1,arr2_index[1],arr2_index[0], -35,-38};
    for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata8[i] = MAT8[i];  }


u3=h3+1;

if (u3==1)

    {int MAT9[]={0,9,10, arr3_v[3], arr3_v[2], arr3_v[1],arr3_v[0],-1,arr3_q[7],arr3_q[6],arr3_q[5],arr3_q[4],arr3_q[3],arr3_q[2],arr3_q[1],arr3_q[0],-1,arr3_soc[3],arr3_soc[2],arr3_soc[1],arr3_soc[0],-1,arr3_index[1],arr3_index[0], -35,-38};
     for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata9[i] = MAT9[i];  } 

else if (u3==2)

    {int MAT10[]={1,0,10, arr3_v[3], arr3_v[2], arr3_v[1],arr3_v[0],-1,arr3_q[7],arr3_q[6],arr3_q[5],arr3_q[4],arr3_q[3],arr3_q[2],arr3_q[1],arr3_q[0],-1,arr3_soc[3],arr3_soc[2],arr3_soc[1],arr3_soc[0],-1,arr3_index[1],arr3_index[0], -35,-38};
    for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata10[i] = MAT10[i];  }

else if (u3==3)

    {int MAT11[]={1,1,10, arr3_v[3], arr3_v[2], arr3_v[1],arr3_v[0],-1,arr3_q[7],arr3_q[6],arr3_q[5],arr3_q[4],arr3_q[3],arr3_q[2],arr3_q[1],arr3_q[0],-1,arr3_soc[3],arr3_soc[2],arr3_soc[1],arr3_soc[0],-1,arr3_index[1],arr3_index[0], -35,-38};
for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata11[i] = MAT11[i];  }

else if (u3==4)

    {int MAT12[]={1,2,10, arr3_v[3], arr3_v[2], arr3_v[1],arr3_v[0],-1,arr3_q[7],arr3_q[6],arr3_q[5],arr3_q[4],arr3_q[3],arr3_q[2],arr3_q[1],arr3_q[0],-1,arr3_soc[3],arr3_soc[2],arr3_soc[1],arr3_soc[0],-1,arr3_index[1],arr3_index[0], -35,-38};
for ( i = 0 ; i < qq ; i++ ) txdata12[i] = MAT12[i];  }
```

After the values are assigned, then I send the data to serial port

```
unsigned char n=26;

uart_multiple (&txdata1, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata2, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata3, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata4, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata5, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata6, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata7, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata8, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata9, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata10, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata11, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata12, n);
```

EDITED: I received all data perfectly except for txdata12,  the first 16 characters shown are wrong, I always got it right for the last 10 characters of txdata12, I have no idea what is wrong…

I really could not figure out after a week of trying, I hope you could give me some hints on what I can work on even with other approach…. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: using variables like `qq` and `arr2_v` also doesn't help readability, there is no need to optimize variable names or white spaces

Comment: post the declarations of txdata1-12, what type are they and what dimensions? You might be having a buffer overrun

Comment: Are all `txdata` declared correctly?

Comment: are those big long arrays really all identical except for the first 2 lines?

Comment: maybe`u3==4` case is never triggered and so you are sending garbage

Comment: It would be good to know how you assign these arrays, i.e. what the code that controls `u1`, `u2` and `u3` looks like. (I suspect that you have wrapped a loop or something around it and don't really need to distinguish the cases at all. If you must initialise all 12 arrays, just initialise them straight away.)

Comment: Does your compiler support inlining of functions? If so: use it to reduce the complexity.

Comment: BTW: maybe your program is correct, but the data is garbled by the serial communication (failing handshake; buffer overrun). BTW2: (12*26) == 312

Comment: @buffer overrun, thanks for your reply, if it is the case of buffer overrun, what could be done? I have updated the post for declaration and am trying to improve the readability, sorry for that

Comment: @samgak, the declaration is updated

Comment: @Matt McNabb, I am sure u3==4 case is triggered as it is displayed in the compiler terminal window

Comment: @M Oehm, the values of u1 u2 and u3 are not fixed as it depends on the output of a sorting program.

Comment: @joop, thanks for your reply, I am using 115.2kbps, how do I check if it is the failing handshake and/or buffer overrun and how could I solve?

Comment: Just send a constant array `char testarray[12*26];` (initialised to some easy to verify contents), and check what is recieved at the other end)

Comment: @joop, thanks for your reply, I did assign constant value to all digits for txdata12, ends up with the same messy data like in the image I uploaded.
int MAT12[]={1,2,10, 1, 2, 4,5,-1,8,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,5,5,3,3,3,3, -35,-38};

Comment: @joop, I notice that for txdata12, for all the trials, only the last ten ascii characters sent are correctly displayed, the first 16 digits are always wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, it is obvious that you are sending faster than the reciever (or the sending UART) can consume. Just to test: add some delays between sending the buffers.

Comment: Declare txdata12 as unsigned char txdata[64]; If that fixes it then it's most likely stack corruption causing the problem. (Only fill and send 26 bytes as before)

Comment: @joop, thanks for your reply, I added delay in between sending txdata11 and txdata12 to UART, I notice a delay but still the same error of the data sent for the first 16 characters, I can't think of why it is only happened to the first 16 characters?

Comment: Also, what is the maximum stack frame size on the device you are using?

Comment: @samgak, thanks for your reply, I did as you suggested by declaring unsigned char txdata12[64]; , it is now displaying all characters of the txdata12 correctly but the error is now moved to txdata11. If I declared all txdata with 64, again the error is back to txdata12

Comment: @samgak: good catch! (I fear the OP does not yet understand it, though)

Comment: @samgak, sorry for my poor understanding, what do you mean by "maximum stack frame size on the device"?

Comment: @joop, forgive my poor understanding, could you please explain to me? I still could not get it why by setting to 64 it moves the error to the previous txdata? 

"it is now displaying all characters of the txdata12 correctly but the error is now moved to txdata11. If I declared all txdata with 64, again the error is back to txdata12"

Comment: The stack frame size is the amount of space allocated on the stack to store local variables. On some embedded devices it can be quite small. I think the problem is stack corruption however. Look through the rest of your function   and double check you arent writing past the end of any arrays.

Comment: @samgak, I don't know what is stack corruption so I googled it up and what I understand is, it could be due to all memory got eaten up or trying to access array out of bound. So, when you say "writing past the end of any arrays", do you mean that it could be that the code is trying to access an array that is out of bound?

Comment: @samgak, I tried declaring all txdata to be size "64" (or "26"), with txdata11 as 72 and txdata12 as 100, and I received all data correctly...but I could not explain why... 

and I read your comment about this "If that fixes it then it's most likely stack corruption causing the problem. (Only fill and send 26 bytes as before)", what do you mean by "Only fill and send 26 bytes as before"? I am sorry for the newbie question

Comment: I just meant to increase the array size but don't change the number of bytes you send with uart_multiple. There are some out of bound memory writes happening somewhere and increasing the array size means that (if you are lucky) they will happen in the unused part of the array instead of over-writing your data. Anyway I would encourage you to put the size back to 26 and find the reason for the corruption, because it could cause problems for you again later.

Comment: @samgak, thank you, I just want to understand what should I do now in order to solve stack corruption, does it mean that I should find out which code is trying to access an array out of bound or???

Comment: I have the feeling that a proper answer to the question could benefit from seeing the whole problem, not just chunks of code out of context. (And that solution will be one loop and one call to `qsort´ or something similarly simple.)

Comment: @user2563812 yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

One thing I find a bit strange in your code is the first arguments in txtData10,11 and 12. In all the others you have e.g.

```
{int MAT6[]={0,6,10
```

where 6 maps on the name txtdata6 but in the case of say 10 you write

```
{int MAT10[]={1,0,10,
```

which seems different, I would expect something like `{0, 10,10` but ok I am just guessing on what is basically a pattern.

Other than that I think you should consider restructuring your code a bit,
use {} around all statements even the one liner for-statements and put them on their own line to make the code more readable and use a switch statement. Use variable names that are descriptive. Format the values so that they are grouped.

Comment: Also `MAT11[]={1,1,10` I think each digit has a single position.

Comment: Yeah it could be, a bit difficult to know what things are for with all these magic numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the poor readability, I have uploaded the image where you can see each digit represents ascii number, for instance, the digit 3 which is '10' represents the symbol ";" in ascii...